# MARS feature importance returns null

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I have been using the Py-earth model, the url can be found here:

And following this turorial [here](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/py-earth/content.html#a-simple-earth-example) :

I have managed to train:

```
model = Earth(max_degree=2, penalty=0.5, minspan_alpha =1, endspan_alpha =1,allow_linear=False,check_every=1,verbose=True)
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

but when `model.summary_feature_importances(sort_by='gcv')` is used , it returns an empty array, which it shouldn't because it provides a result like this in the tutorial:

```
            nb_subsets    gcv    rss
lstat       0.42          0.78   0.78   
rm          0.25          0.12   0.12   
crim        0.17          0.06   0.06   
dis         0.17          0.04   0.04   
black       0.00          0.00   0.00   
ptratio     0.00          0.00   0.00   
tax         0.00          0.00   0.00   
rad         0.00          0.00   0.00   
age         0.00          0.00   0.00   
nox         0.00          0.00   0.00   
chas        0.00          0.00   0.00   
indus       0.00          0.00   0.00   
zn          0.00          0.00   0.00
```

This tutorial can be found [here](https://notebook.community/fclesio/learning-space/Python/.ipynb_checkpoints/MARS%20Simple%20Tutorial-checkpoint).

Comment: You need to use the `feature_importance_type` argument when constructing the `Earth` object.  See https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/py-earth/_modules/pyearth/earth.html.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I believe you need to set the `feature_importance_type`parameter when calling `Earth()`.

Try this:

```
model = Earth(feature_importance_type='gcv', max_degree=2, penalty=0.5, minspan_alpha =1, endspan_alpha =1,allow_linear=False,check_every=1,verbose=True)
model.fit(X_train,y_train)

model.summary_feature_importances(sort_by='gcv')
```